# Is it possible to pass parameter between napili template built with lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, community, napili

I am working on napili community template pages built with lightning components. There is a requirement to pass value from a lightning component in page 1 to a lightning component in page 2..

I tried using application event but lightning component in page 2 is not able to handle the event raised from other component in page 1.

Any suggestions on how this requirement can be achieved.

Comment: You can access the query string from your component by having a string parameter with the same name. You might try this.

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141177/how-do-i-access-query-string-data-from-custom-lightning-component-in-community