# How do I access query string data from custom lightning component in Community (Napili theme)

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components

When testing the component I am able to pass values to string attributes on the application in using a query string of the same name, but I am not sure how to do the same thing if the component is embedded in a communities page.  I am using the napili theme if that makes any difference.

The attribute I am trying to set has a design attribute defined like this:

```
<design:attribute name="selectedExhibit" label="Exhibit Public Name" description="The Exhibit Public name to be use to lookup the schedule." />
```

Is there something I need to enter in the property editor:

[image: Property Editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the property editor you enter {!yourParamName} as the value.  For anyone looking for the answer.

Be careful the value that is passed to the javascript in the controller does not appear to be url decoded, I had to add some code in my controller init like this to get it to work consistently

```
if (!$A.util.isEmpty(component.get("v.selectedExhibit"))){
            component.set("v.selectedExhibit", decodeURIComponent(component.get("v.selectedExhibit")));
}
```